# Google Chrome confirm close

Tags: google-chrome, window-manager

Many a time and oft I get confused between *close tab* (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>) and *close* (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>) in Google Chrome, closing dozens of tabs at once.

How do I specify a close prompt before closing multiple tabs on Chrome (version 18.0.1025.168)?

I have tried `chrome://flags/`, and the wrench menues but found no such option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling "Warn Before Quitting" should prevent that from happening. You can find that option in the Chrome menu in the menubar.

When enabled, you need to hold down <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for a bit before it actually quits.

[image]

Comment: Where is this done?

Comment: As I said, in the "Chrome" menu in the menubar.

Comment: +1 Works. Sorry, too little coffee for this time of the day. Thanks!

Comment: Screenshot for extra clarity :)

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently possible but you could do cmd+shift+T a number of times, until you have all your taps restored.